# Page Life Cycle, does db connection go in Page_Load

Tags: c#, asp.net, database-connection, parameter-passing, page-lifecycle

Currently I have The following code:

```
void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
 {       
       string connectionString = "server=abc;database=abc;uid=abc;pwd=1234";
       SqlConnection mySqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
       string procedureString = "Callin_Insert";
       SqlCommand mySqlCommand = mySqlConnection.CreateCommand();
       mySqlCommand.CommandText = procedureString;
       mySqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
       mySqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@LVDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now;
       mySqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@LVTime", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now;
       mySqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@CuID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = CustID;
       mySqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Type", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Keypress;
       mySqlConnection.Open();
       mySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
       SqlDataAdapter mySqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
       mySqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand = mySqlCommand;
       mySqlConnection.Close();
}
```

Basically, I am opening a connection to the Database during the page_load.  I am also closing that connection in page_load.  Part of my problem is that the CustID & Keypress are not getting passed, because they occur later in the page life cycle.  What is the best way to open the connection, get the 2 variables (when I they are entered by the user), pass them to the database, and close the connection.

Somethings I have tried is running it _OnLoad.  But this didn't work either.

Any thoughts or suggestion, are greatly appreciated.

Comment: `because they occur later in the page life cycle` Why not do all of this later in the page's life cycle when all the data is available?

Comment: I have tried that, by adding all this in the OnLoad section, with no luck.  Where in the page life cycle would you suggest adding it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of SqlConnection is of IDisposible interface means it is much safer to wrap your code with using statement like this.

```
string connectionString = "server=abc;database=abc;uid=abc;pwd=1234";
using (SqlConnection mySqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    string procedureString = "Callin_Insert";
    SqlCommand mySqlCommand = new SqlCommand(procedureString, mySqlConnection);
    mySqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    mySqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@LVDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now;
    mySqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@LVTime", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now;
    mySqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@CuID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = CustID;
    mySqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Type", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Keypress;

    mySqlConnection.Open();
    mySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

    //i have no idea what does this mean, data adapter is for filling Datasets and DataTables
    SqlDataAdapter mySqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    mySqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand = mySqlCommand;
}
```

Second of all i offer you to use SqlDataSourceObject control which will make much easier to work with cases like yours.

It will know how to deal with Page.IsPostBack that you haven't implemented but should, paging and other stuff you need.

Comment: SqlDataAdapter mySqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    mySqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand = mySqlCommand;
was added, to write the parameters; @LVDate, @LVTime, @CuID, @Type back to the database.  I tried this out and it worked, but only worked when I put everything in the page load.  So, the code you have presented above, where in the cycle would you put it?

Comment: As i've said in my Second Of All, i would use SqlDataSource control or ObjectDataSource control to deal with Page LiveCycles

Comment: Ok I got you, thanks.  And what about the issue of closing the connection.  I see where it opens, but there is no close, is that apart of the IDisposible interface inherently?

Comment: sometimes you will not reach connection.close() line because of anykind of error. using IDisposible objects allow you to close these at any case using "using" statement. Same goes for SqlDataReader or any type of DataReader whether it is XML or Webrequest.

Answer (score 0):

Think there are a few problems here... first of all why are you running your query and then passing it to a data adapter? The data adapter will run the select command when queried.

I suggest creating a SqlDataSource on your aspx page (not code behind) and bind your control to it. Then hook up the Selecting event and in there populate your parameters. That should happen later in the page lifecycle so your parameter values will then be set.

Comment: +1 for not calling `ExecuteNonQuery`, but -1 for suggesting he keep using `SqlDataAdapter`. `SqlDataSource` is much nicer.

Comment: True John, in fact I did mean SqlDataSource in the aspx. That's what has the Selecting event. Been a while since I used webforms but I should have checked first so shame on me!